# SQL: Aggregate function returning 0's when using WHERE filter

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table with 10 columns listing results of a marketing campaign including person name, date, residence area, request, and response.

The request column is always a number, indicating the number of survey requests we've sent a specific person.

The response column is a number from 0 to X, representing the number of surveys a person has responded to take.

Now, when I look through the actual table, there are probably around 10% response rate. With lots of non-zero entries in the response column.

However, when I write an aggregate function like this:

```
SELECT person, date, SUM(requests), SUM(response)
FROM analytics.SurveyResults0304
WHERE group_type = 'Youth'
GROUP BY person, date;
```

I get a correct number for SUM(requests), but I get a big fat "0"  for SUM(response)? 
It's the same for all 3 group types. It returns a 0 for SUM(response)

Update: it works fine when I don't include the group_type filter, but how come I can't use it with the WHERE filter?

Thanks!!!

EDIT2: Sample Table

```
  Person    Date       Group_Type   Requests Response  Neighborhood FirstName  
  --------  --------   -----------  -------- --------  ------------ ---------
  Nixon     3/3/2013    Youth          3        3  Chinatown    Richard
  Clinton   3/3/2013    Youth          4        0  Gunhill      Bill
  Mao       3/3/2013    Youth          5        0  Berryville   Chairman
  Nixon     3/4/2013    Youth         17        2  Townsford    Richard
  Gates     3/3/2013    Elderly       41        5  Chinatown    Bill
  Gates     3/4/2013    Elderly        0        0  Chinatown    Bill
  Gates     3/5/2013    Elderly        0        0  Chinatown    Bill
  Gates     3/6/2013    Elderly        0        0  Chinatown    Bill
```

For example
When I do:

```
SELECT  SUM(requests), SUM(response)
FROM analytics.SurveyResults0304
WHERE group_type = 'Youth';
```

It returns 70 for request, and 0 for response across the board.

Comment: can you give smple records with your desired result?

Comment: Do SELECT response FROM analytics.SurveyResults0304 WHERE group_type = 'Youth' - are you getting any non zero values?

Comment: barc0de: interesting: it still returns only 0. Maybe it's not the aggregate function thats messing me up.

Comment: Why dont you try `SELECT person, date,response FROM analytics.SurveyResults0304 WHERE group_type = 'Youth' GROUP BY person, date;` and check manually if some comes to zero.

Comment: What results do you get if you change the condition to be `group_type like 'Youth%'`? (I have a suspicion that group_type may be space-padded.)

Comment: Thanks for all your ideas guys!!  I;ve found the mistake. I've been selecting data from the wrong table.  Oof. Do I feel dumb now

Comment: Mark: Thanks, thats very useful advice actually. I will keep that in mind for future references.

Comment: Can you post the table def? Are both request and response numeric fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be working. See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ded19/1) built from your data sample.

May be you have **extra spaces and/or tabs** in your `Group_Type` column?

```
PERSON  DATE                 SUM(REQUESTS)  SUM(RESPONSE)
--------------------------------------------------------
Clinton March, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000    4   0
Mao     March, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000    5   0
Nixon   March, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000    3   3
Nixon   March, 04 2013 00:00:00+0000    17  2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It turns out it's not my code that's the problem, it was the table's problem.